# How to use a selector finding an frame (iframe) using Playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I have a trivial question that I can't find an answer to using Microsoft Playwright framework. According to [documentation](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.1.1&path=docs%2Fcore-concepts.md&q=pages-and-frames) you can fetch an iframe with the following code:

```
const frame = page.frame('frame-login');
```

But how do I use a selector to find and interact with an iframe? I need to use a CSS selector to find my iframe since it does not have an id.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`elementHandle.contentFrame()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-content-frame)

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.class-name')

const elementHandle = await page.$('.class-name')
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame()
```

From that moment you can interact with the content of the `<iframe>` like: `await frame.<method_name>`.

Comment: `page.$` is marked "deprecated" in 2023, but there does not seem to be a workaround for finding a frame by selector...

Comment: Microsoft tries to push users toward their "locator" ecosystem from the Chrome Devtools `$` `$$` (+ElementHandle) solutions. I wrote about this in more depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214541/12412595 (before they really deprecated it). I am not aware of any workarounds at the moment, but the Playwright community on Github or even here is always helpful, you can try to ask what is the preferred way to grab frames with locators.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `ElementHandle` calling `$` and then call the [contentFrame](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe) function:

```js
const handle = await page.$('.frame');
const contentFrame = await handle.contentFrame();
```