# Playwright: how can i wait until the content of an iframe has been loaded

Tags: iframe, playwright

I the following example an iframe with the src `myurl` will be injected in the page.
I can find the iframe dom element but without the explicit wait the `page.frame` function returns null.
I guess this is because `page.frame` does not wait for the iframe to be loaded.
How can i wait until the content of an iframe has been loaded?

```js
await expect(page.locator('iframe')).toHaveCount(1);
await page.waitForTimeout(2000); // explicit wait should be removed
const frame = page.frame({url: new RegExp('.*/myurl.*', 'i')});
expect(frame).not.toBeNull();
```

Comment: What sort of content are you trying to access in that frame? Do you have a snippet of the relevant HTML or the site you're working with? Seems like [`waitForSelector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596683/6243352) may work to replace the wait, depending on the site.

Comment: The iframe can contain all kinds of html but typically it‘s a full blown web application that might take a few seconds to load and be rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible solutions have been suggested by Yury Semikhatsky:

```js
const frame = page.frames()[0];
await frame.waitForURL(new RegExp('.*/myurl.*', 'i'));
```

or like this:

```js
const iframeElement = await page.locator('iframe').elementHandle()
const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame();
await frame.waitForURL(new RegExp('.*/myurl.*', 'i'));
```

Comment: You probably want to update this code just a tiny bit to shows how to also deal with the iframe failing to load the url it was told to load.